# User groups issue

Tags: permissions, user-groups

Recently I noticed strange thing that I can't figure out searching the web.

The `groups` and `id` give

```
$ groups 
q
$ id
uid=1000(q) gid=1000(q) groups=1000(q)
```

But explicitly passed arg change the result

```
$ groups q
q : q adm tty disk lp uucp dialout cdrom sudo audio dip video plugdev 
users lpadmin pulse pulse-access sambashare vboxusers input wireshark docker libvirt

$ id q
uid=1000(q) gid=1000(q) groups=1000(q),4(adm),5(tty),6(disk),7(lp),10(uucp),20(dialout),24(cdrom),27(sudo),29(audio),30(dip),44(video),46(plugdev),100(users),108(lpadmin),122(pulse),123(pulse-access),124(sambashare),125(vboxusers),148(input),153(wireshark),155(docker),160(libvirt)
```

From man

> SYNOPSIS
>
> id [OPTION]... [USER]
>
> DESCRIPTION
>
> Print user and group information for the specified USER, or (when USER omitted) for the current user.

After

```
$ sudo -i -u q

$ groups
q adm tty disk lp uucp dialout cdrom sudo audio dip video plugdev users lpadmin pulse pulse-access sambashare vboxusers input wireshark docker libvirt
$ id
uid=1000(q) gid=1000(q) groups=1000(q),4(adm),5(tty),6(disk),7(lp),10(uucp),20(dialout),24(cdrom),27(sudo),29(audio),30(dip),44(video),46(plugdev),100(users),108(lpadmin),122(pulse),123(pulse-access),124(sambashare),125(vboxusers),148(input),153(wireshark),155(docker),160(libvirt)
```

This issue has side effect regarding to file system items access. Apps like VirtualBox can't get access to e.g. `/dev/vboxusb` until `sudo -i -u q`.

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. How to fix?